# How to open an existing window with IronPython

Tags: .net, wpf, ironpython

I'm trying to learn some IronPython to perhaps speed up the development process time. I'm just trying to port over some simple commands and currently I'm stuck on opening an existing window. In C# I would do something like:

```
var about = new AboutWin();
about.Show();
```

Does anybody know how to go about doing this in IronPython? I'm sure it's ridiculously easy just like everything else seams to be with IronPython.

Answer (score 1):

This should do the trick:

```
import clr
clr.AddReference('PresentationFramework')
import System

from System.Windows.Markup import XamlReader
from System.Windows import Application

XAML_str = """<Window xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml" Width="250" Height="100">
    <TextBox Text="Hello from IronPython" />
</Window>"""

app = Application()
app.Run(XamlReader.Parse(XAML_str))
```

See my blog for [bigger example](http://gui-at.blogspot.com/2009/11/inotifypropertychanged-in-ironpython.html).

Comment: +1 to your answer - i have missed that he is trying to run WPF application

Answer (score 0):

As far as i know you can do this the following way:

```
import clr

clr.AddReference("System.Windows.Forms")

from System.Windows.Forms import Form,Labels

myForm = Form()
myForm.Text = 'Test'
label = Label()
label.Text = 'Label Test'
myForm.Controls.Add(label)
myForm.Show()
```

E.g in your case you first need to add reference to the AboutWin and then use it the same way:

```
import clr

clr.AddReference(<put your assembly name here>)

from <namespace> import AboutWin

aWin = AboutWin()
aWin.Show()
```

Comment: import clr

clr.AddReference(Wpf_Python)

from Wpf_Python import AboutWin

aWin = AboutWin()
aWin.Show()

Unfortunately this didn't do the trick. I get an error that says "Could not add reference to assembly AboutWin". Am I missing something?

Comment: I think you have to check your reference name or namespace used. Think you have specified it the wrong way. If clr.AddReference works correctly then check from statement to be sure that the right name specified